# Unable to run this Java-SQL program

Tags: java, sql, cmd

I'm a complete noob and am trying to run this program from the command prompt:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exp12 {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaexp";

    static final String u = "root"; 
    static final String p = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, u, p);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Enter the credentials: ");
            System.out.print("> Employee Number: ");
            int no = in.nextInt();

            System.out.print("> Employee Name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("> Department Number: ");
            int dept = in.nextInt();

            System.out.print("> Employee Salary: ");
            int sal = in.nextInt();         

            String sql = "INSERT INTO emp VALUES (" + no + ", " + name + ", " + dept + ", " + sal + ")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }

        catch(SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if(stmt != null)
                    con.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException sqle1) {
                sqle1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the program compiles all right
[Error-free compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QORPf.png)

When I try to run this code with java interpreter, as below:

```
code> java -cp [classpath of the .jar mysql driver] Exp12
```

I get this error:

```
could not find or load main class Exp12
```

When I try

```
code>java -cp [classpath of the main class] Exp12
```

I get:

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

When I try:

```
code>java -cp [classpath of .jar file]:[classpath of main class] Exp12
```

I still get "could not find or load main class Exp12"

I've set the classpath in environment variables to both the .jar file and the Exp12 file, but am still unable to run the program.

How can I run this program?

Answer (score 0):

Should be the last option. Do you have quotes around the list of paths?

`java -cp "[classpath of .jar file]:[classpath of main class]" Exp12`

Some more general tips: https://java2blog.com/could-not-find-or-load-main-class/

Comment: Tried that, it didn't give any errors, but instead listed all options associated with java in cmd.